# Getting TypeError: rndm_json_data_gen() missing 1 required positional argument: 'rangenum'

Tags: python, typeerror

**Error message:**
`TypeError: rndm_json_data_gen() missing 1 required positional argument: 'rangenum'`.

I don't see what is missing. I have looked at many of the similar threads on stackoverflow, but can't see how anything applies to my situation.

This code runs first i.e  at terminal, Python `handler.py`:

```
#########################################################
##              HANDLER.PY                             ##
#########################################################
import psycopg2
from lib.feeder import Feeder
from lib.tle import TLE
from lib.import_data import IMPORTDATA
from lib.random_json import DATA_GEN

##TECHNICALLY THIS COMES PRE-LOADED
conn_string = "database connection"

# print the connection string we will use to connect
#print("Connecting to database\n    ->%s" % (conn_string))
# get a connection, if a connect cannot be made an exception will be raised here
conn = psycopg2.connect(conn_string)

##THIS IS THE PART THAT I’M TRYING TO GET TO WORK

TypeProcessor = IMPORTDATA()
num_json_items = 5

#####Error happens with last item here######
Feeder(conn).insertOrUpdateItem("database_table", TypeProcessor.getDictionary(),
TypeProcessor.getIds(), TypeProcessor.getModifiedKey(), TypeProcessor.getUpdateOnConflict(),
DATA_GEN.rndm_json_data_gen(num_json_items))

print("Import Data complete")
'''
## Below was what was in the last spot, where the problem is occurring,
## before I started changing it to a method
    {"uuid": "UUID1", "column1": "data1", "column2": data2, "column3": "data3", \
    "column4": "data4", "file_name": "filename", "load_date": "2020-12-09"}
```

---

```
#########################################################
##              IMPORT_DATA.PY                         ##
#########################################################

modified_key = "load_date"
update_on_conflict = True
ids = ["uuid"]
dictionary = {
    "uuid": {"input_field": "uid", "update_on_conflict": False},
    "column1": {"input_field": "column1", "update_on_conflict": True},
    "column2": {"input_field": "column2", "update_on_conflict": True},
    "column3": {"input_field": "column3", "update_on_conflict": True},
    "column4": {"input_field": "column4", "update_on_conflict": True},
    "load_date": {"input_field": "load_date", "update_on_conflict": True}
    };

class IMPORTDATA():

    def getDictionary(self):
        return dictionary;

    def getIds(self):
        return ids;

    def getModifiedKey(self):
        return modified_key;

    def getUpdateOnConflict(self):
        return modified_key;
```

---

```
###############################################
##            RANDOM_JSON.PY                 ##
###############################################

import json
from faker import Faker
import random
from random import randint
from datetime import datetime

class DATA_GEN():
def rndm_json_data_gen(self,rangenum):
    fake = Faker()
    Faker.seed(0)
    for _ in range(rangenum):
        import_data={
            "uuid": fake.bothify(text='UUUID##########'),\
            "column1": fake.bothify(text='Data##'), \
            "column2": fake.bothify(text='##'), \
            "column3": fake.bothify(text='##'), \
            "file_nm": fake.file_name(), \
            “import_date”: datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M:%S')
        }
        return import_data;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have defined `rndm_json_data_gen` as an instance method, but you are calling it like a static method. Therefore the `self` parameter is not being fulfilled automatically. You either need to instantiate it first,

```
data_gen = DATA_GEN()

Feeder(conn).insertOrUpdateItem("database_table", TypeProcessor.getDictionary(),
TypeProcessor.getIds(), TypeProcessor.getModifiedKey(), TypeProcessor.getUpdateOnConflict(),
data_gen.rndm_json_data_gen(num_json_items))
```

or mark it `@staticmethod` and remove the `self` param. Since you're not using `self` in the method body, I think you might as well make it static.

By the way, [official Python style](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#class-names) calls for PascalCase class names, not CAPS.